# Remove single quotes in python list

Tags: python

What is the best way to remove single quotes in a python list?

I have the following input:

```
['{"name": "Brian", "city": "Seattle"}', '{"name": "Rick", "city": "Boston"}']
```

But i want the following output:

```
[{"name": "Brian", "city": "Seattle"}, {"name": "Rick", "city": "Boston"}]
```

Comment: `[ast.literal_eval(k) for k in l]`

Comment: How are you creating the input list?

Comment: From what you posted, you have a list of strings. There are no single quotes to remove, just things to parse, maybe

Comment: I mean to remove single quote around json document in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `json.loads`.

```
import json

a_list = ['{"name": "Brian", "city": "Seattle"}', '{"name": "Rick", "city": "Boston"}']

dict_list = [json.loads(x) for x in a_list]
```

Output: `[{'name': 'Brian', 'city': 'Seattle'}, {'name': 'Rick', 'city': 'Boston'}]`

Comment: Thanks. I am going to use json.loads() for now unless ast.literal_eval as better performance than json.loads()